# hidden column issue with Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have rendered a hidden column using the fnRender function like this

`"aTargets": [0],

 "fnRender": function ( oObj ) {

                 return '<input id="test" name="test" value="'+ oObj.aData[0] +'" type="hidden" />';

 }`

and under `aoColumns` have defined `null` for it.

Now this field shows up as a column in the Datatables, which I do not want.

I tried the attribute `bVisible:false` , but that also removes it from rendering , hence I am unable to get the value from the hidden field.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a workaround , clubbed the value of the hidden field with a visible field with a expression "#" in between.

Performing a split on the String retrieved to get the value of the hidden field.

Answer (score 4):

You need to hide the first column only :

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { "bVisible":    false, "aTargets": [0]}
]
```

Comment: Yes , I tried this hides the column entirely,hence I am unable to get the value of the hidden field.